# Выровнять элементы по нижнему краю

Tags: html, css

На картинке, которую я прикрутил ниже, элементы не сходятся, и мне необходимо их как-то выровнять и зафиксировать, чтобы их отображение на других мониторах было нормальным, ибо чем меньше моник, тем больше плывет элемент.

[image]

Comment: В чем вопрос? Дайте на код посмотреть. Предположительно, у вас бордер схлопывается с высотой инпута.

Comment: Копать в сторону различных высот картинки в одном поле и шрифта в другом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте верстку, как в таблице, то бишь родительский:

```
  display:table;
```

А иконка и поле ввода:

```
  display:table-cell;
```

А размеры уже по родителю ориентировать.

Answer (score 0):

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  position: relative;
}

input, i {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  padding-left: 40px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
  /*background: ... */
}
```

```html
<label><i></i><input placeholder=email></label>
```